# Kivy add_widget only displays the last widget added

Tags: python, kivy

My problem in the following code is:
The screen only shows the last button added, when it should show them all side-by-side

What is the problem and what can be done to fix it?

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class check(Screen, GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(check, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=3
        btn1 = ToggleButton(text='Male', group='sex',)
        btn2 = ToggleButton(text='Female', group='sex', state='down')
        btn3 = ToggleButton(text='Mixed', group='sex',)

        self.add_widget(btn3)
        self.add_widget(btn2)
        self.add_widget(btn1)


class Bridges(App):
    def build(self):       
        sm = ScreenManager()

        newkid = check(name='newkid')
        sm.add_widget(newkid)

        return sm
Bridges().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the order of inheritance.

Your class `check` inherits from two classes, `Screen` and `GridLayout`. And the position of the parent class matters, because the property and method inheritance goes left-to-right.

What I mean is - the methods that are responsible for the layout are inherited from `Screen` and not from `GridLayout` as you desire.
The fix is simple: swap the class order in the `check` definition:

```
class check(GridLayout, Screen):
```

instead of

```
class check(Screen, GridLayout):
```